# How is DXA 1.7 consuming the Discovery service?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I am upgrading my DXA 1.2 to DXA 1.7 with SDL Web 8.5. I understand I need to provide the Discovery service URL in my DXA web app's `web.config` file to make the application work, and it is working as expected as well. So there is no concern's with that.

I was looking into DXA 1.7 core as well as Site project files to identify where the `discovery-service-uri` key is used from `web.config`. But I dont find a file which using this key. I am wondering how the Discovery service is consumed by DXA?

Answer (score 2):

DXA uses the SDL Web Content Interaction Libraries (CIL) to communicate with the Content Interaction Services (CIS).  The `discovery-service-uri` setting is one of the app settings used by the CIL.

So, indeed, you won’t find any references to that setting in the DXA codebase.